# Error using Primefaces growl, cannot be cast to AutoUpdatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've used Primefaces multiple times.  It's excellent.  But this time I don't know why:

I cannot add a growl component, error is: org.primefaces.component.growl.Growl cannot be cast to org.primefaces.component.api.AutoUpdatable

The same for p:messages

It's possibly due to some errors in my facelet.  But I compare this to a successful facelet that I wrote before, and I cannot figure out what's the problem.  The facelet is question is (delete p:growl and all go well):

```
<body>

    <ui:composition template="./../../WEB-INF/master.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="top">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListAccountHolderTitle}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                <p:growl id="growl"/>
                <p:dataTable value="#{accountHolderBean.items}" var="holder">
                    <p:column headerText="Type">#{holder.name}</p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    Type
                    <h:inputText id="type1" required="true" value="#{accountHolderBean.selected.type}"/>
                    Name
                    <h:inputText id="name1" value="#{accountHolderBean.selected.name}"/>
                    Field
                    <h:inputText id="field1" accesskey="f" value="#{accountHolderBean.field}"/>
                    Value
                    <h:inputText id="val" accesskey="v" value="#{accountHolderBean.val}"/>
                    All attributes
                    <h:outputText id="attrs" value="#{accountHolderBean.allAttributes}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandLink update="attrs" actionListener="#{accountHolderBean.update}">Update</p:commandLink>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> org.primefaces.component.growl.Growl cannot be cast to org.primefaces.component.api.AutoUpdatable
> ```

This suggests that you've both PrimeFaces 2.x and 3.x libraries in your webapp's runtime classpath. The `AutoUpdatable` was introduced in PrimeFaces 3.0 while the `Growl` already exist before in 2.x, but it didn't implement `AutoUpdatable` until PrimeFaces 3.0.

Cleanup your classpath and get rid of the offending old PrimeFaces 2.x library.

Comment: I tried primefaces 3, switched briefly to 2, and back to 3 again.  It's not sufficient to remove the Primefaces 2 Library, I need to remove the project directory.  But this works. Thanks.